# Replace “this field is required” message in parsley without repeating

Tags: parsley.js

According to [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/) I can do it like this:

```
<input data-parsley-required-message="this field is required" />
```

But this requires to repeat the data-parsley-required-message for each input.
I would like to change message just in one place, is it possible without writing a  [custom validation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#custom)?

There is API for [updating error message](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#ui-for-javascript):

```
updateError(name, {message: , assert: , updateClass: true});
```

But I cannot find method "updateError" on window.Parsley and not clear what "assert" means if I already can provide name for "required-message" validation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the doc, parsley options are inherited from the form and the global level.

So you could specify it once at the form level with the data attribute

```
<form data-parsley-required-message="this field is required">
```

Or via javascript, at the form or global level:

```
$('form').parsley().options.requiredMessage = "this field is required"
$.Parsley.options.requiredMessage = "this field is required"
```